# Passing array data is null when using Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, parcelable

I want to pass an `arraylist` between 2 `activity` but I met a problem

In `FirstActivity` the `ArrayList` is not null but In `SecondActivity` it's null and I don't know What is happened

My **Intent**:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, NewContactActivity.class);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("CONTACT_ARRAY", mData);
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

My **SecondActivity**:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
ArrayList<Contact> lstContact = this.getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("CONTACT_ARRAY");
edtPhone.setText(lstContact.get(0).getPhone());
```

My **Contact class**:

```
public class Contact implements Parcelable {
    private String id;
    private String Name;
    private String Fname;
    private String Phone;
    private String Email;


    public Contact(String id, String Name, String Fname, String Phone, String Email) {
        this.id = id;
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Fname = Fname;
        this.Email = Email;
        this.Phone = Phone;
    }

    public Contact(Parcel in) {
        this.id = in.readString();
        this.Name = in.readString();
        this.Fname = in.readString();
        this.Email = in.readString();
        this.Phone = in.readString();
    }

    //Getter
    public String getId() { return id; }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public String getFname() {
        return Fname;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return Email;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return Phone;
    }

    //Setter

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public void setFname(String fname) {
        Fname = fname;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        Email = email;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone){ Phone = phone; }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(id);
        dest.writeString(Name);
        dest.writeString(Fname);
        dest.writeString(Phone);
        dest.writeString(Email);

    }
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Contact> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Contact>() {
        public Contact createFromParcel(Parcel in)
        {
            return new Contact(in);
        }
        public Contact[] newArray(int size)
        {
            return new Contact[size];
        }
    };
}
```

How can I resolve this ? **Thanks you so much**

Comment: Check your typecasting in SecondActivity.

Comment: can you share code how to add data on list

Comment: Yes sure, I'm using `ContentResolver` and `Cursor` to get contact data to contact list

Comment: @jasonmomoa Did you tried to debug this by looking at what extra data you are sending through intent and what are you getting on the other activity? If none of the answers work you can try this, This helps me most of the time.

Comment: @deepakkumar I tried to pass a String Variable from `FirstActivity` to `SecondActivity`, and this work perfectly but with ArrayList is no.

Comment: @jasonmomoa No, no I meant run the app in debug mode and see each variable state. See this documentation https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://developer.android.com/studio/debug&ved=2ahUKEwiQ36Cx8NHiAhVGuo8KHQUzDaMQFjABegQIBxAM&usg=AOvVaw2nKjq6dxakMEtcZRPifU8w&cshid=1559721850359

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the arraylist and not single object

```
ArrayList<Contact> lstContact = createContactList();

i.putParcelableArrayListExtra("CONTACT_ARRAY", (ArrayList) lstContact );
```

while in second activity

```
 ciArr = (List) i.getParcelableArrayListExtra("CONTACT_ARRAY");
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `this.getIntent()` with your `intent`. You are not using it at all.

Comment: are you sure your `mData` is not empty ?

Answer (score 0):

**Try with below code.**

```
private void gotoNextActivity() {
    Intent intent=new Intent(this,NewContactActivity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelableArrayList("CONTACT_ARRAY", contactsList);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

**NewContactActivity.class**

```
  ArrayList<BeanClass> listFromActivity1=new ArrayList<>(); 
  listFromActivity1=this.getIntent().getExtras().getParcelableArrayList("CONTACT_ARRAY");
  if (listFromActivity1 != null) {
       Log.d("Contact List",""+listFromActivity1.toString());
     }
```

Comment: @@ not working, This way is good but I don't know why it's still not working

Comment: Can you debug and see your arraylist is empty or not ?

Comment: in FirstActivity is not null, but in SecondActivity is null. And I don't know What is happened ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to maintain the same order in your constructor and in writeToParcel function.

```
 @Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(id);
    dest.writeString(Name);
    dest.writeString(Fname);
    dest.writeString(Email);
    dest.writeString(Phone);


}
```